# ng-bootstrap modal not appearing

Tags: bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

In my Angular 5 app I'm using ng-bootstrap but it's not appearing.  I'm just trying to open it up the normal way from typescript:

```js
private modalRef: NgbModalRef;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

openModal(content) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
}
```

With a super simple HTML test.

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    Hi mom!
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
        (click)="openModal(content)">Add AR</button>
```

I see that my openModal is in fact being called, but the dialog doesn't appear.  No errors are being put into the console either.

Comment: Did you include Bootstrap 4 CSS?

Comment: Shoot.  I think it's including an older version of bootstrap.  It's using our company's "look and feel" includes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    Hi mom!
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
        (click)="openModal(content)">Add AR</button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.